# Margin doesn't work on TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, tablelayoutpanel

I am trying to add buttons on run time according to the table count in the database. I was adding them with top and left properties on code but they don't change with the form size. So I tried to implement TableLayoutPanel to my code. I am able to create my buttons on TableLayoutPanel. But TableLayoutPanel cover the whole form. I want to give some space to sides. I tried new Padding but it doesn't work. I create panel or workflowpanel and add my tablelayoutpanel in it. And give margin to them but that also didn't work out.

Here is my code.

```
private void frmTables_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Panel panel = new Panel();
            this.Controls.Add(panel);
            panel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            panel.Margin = new Padding(20);
            TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel1 = new TableLayoutPanel();
            panel.Controls.Add(tableLayoutPanel1);
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(gnl.connectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [TableId],[IsEmpty] FROM [serin].[dbo].[Table] WHERE[IsActive] = 1", con);
            tableLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = true;
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 1;
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50F));
            tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 4;
            tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 25F));
            tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 25F));
            tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 25F));
            tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 25F));
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Clear();
            tableLayoutPanel1.AutoSize = true;
            tableLayoutPanel1.Margin = new Padding(5);
            tableLayoutPanel1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;



            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();
            //int left = 104;
            //int top = 79;
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i % 4 == 0 && i != 0)
                {
                    tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount + 1;
                    tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50F));
                    //left = 104;
                    //top += 120;
                }
                Button newButton = new Button();
                buttons.Add(newButton);
                this.Controls.Add(newButton);
                makeTables(newButton, i, int.Parse(dt.Rows[i][1].ToString()));
                tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(newButton);
                newButton.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                //newButton.Left = left;
                //left += 136;
                //newButton.Top = top;

            }
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount + 1;
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50F));
```

Comment: Don't use Layout Panel it has limited properties.  Use a Panel and create your own grids.  It looks like you are just placing text in each of the panel cells.  So you can make a one large panel and then make each cell another panel or add a text box as each cell.  It you want to use the Layout panel then add a text box to each grid which will allow you to have margins.  The margins for the text will be the left, top, width and height of the textbox.  Then place each string into the textbox instead of the panel.

Comment: You can stay with the TLP if you want a table! - But Fill will win over the Margin! Remove the dock and set all four anchors instead!

Answer (score 0):

Margin does not work for TableLayoutPanel. You can only use [Padding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/margin-and-padding-in-windows-forms-controls).

```
tableLayoutPanel1.Padding = new Padding(5);
```